# Media Queries não funciona

Tags: css, media-queries

Estou desenvolvendo um site em WordPress que precisa ser responsivo e para tanto estou utilizando media queries:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)">
...
</head>
```

Ao testa-lo em dispositivos móveis porem ele não está chamando as css do arquivo mobile.css. O que devo fazer?
O site é [este aqui](http://recantodomus.com.br/wptemp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar o media query inline no seu mobile.css

Exemplo: [Use-media-query-inline-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023157/use-media-query-inline-style)

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { /* Change to whatever media query you require */
    .bg {
         background: url(background_highres.jpg);
    }
}
```